# install precompiled packages into python3 virtualenv

Tags: python, package, lxml, virtualenv, pip

I am working on an application in Python 3.3 on Win7 x64. When installing lxml with pip

```
pip install lxml
```

i always get the following error:

```
lxml error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

This question has been answered on SO before, but the solutions usually point to executables (as it occurs due to compiler problems). However, I want to install lxml into a virtualenv:

```
> cd \venv\Scripts
> activate
(venv) > pip install lxml
```

Obviously this get me the same `vcvarsall.bat` error as before; clearly I still don't have the right compiler installed.

How do I install a precompiled executable ([like these](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)) into a virtualenv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, however I'm unsure whether this is a clean or even sane way of doing it.

As the `vcvarsall.bat` error occurs due to a misconfigured or wrong compiler, use a precompiled package from the source in the question. If you install that package into the system python installation, it will put the scripts into

```
C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages
```

after installation, there should be two folders: `lxml` and `lxml-3.2.3-py3.3.egg-info`. By copying both folders into the respective folder of the `virtualenv`, the package should be available there as well. For example if the virtualenv is in `C:\venv\`, copy the folders to `C:\venv\Lib\site-packages\`.